# How to make camera move in the circle around the object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Well, i am making a small Unity game that i need to face the camera around an object, i need whenever i touch '->' camera with move in a circle around an object, i guest i can put that circle into the Equation of circle and then i will put x coordinate in that equation -> z coordinate and then i can make the new position of the camera. For that Facing function i can use transform.LookAt(). But it is the complex way and inconvenience way to code, so please give me more simple way if you think out.

Thanks alot !!!!

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way is to make the camera to child of an empty gameobject which will be act like an "anchor"

Add an empty gameobject as child to your object that you want your camera to rotate around.

After that, add your camera to that empty gameobject that you created recently.

If you rotate that "anchor" empty gameobject (now it will be not empty because there will be camera as child) your camera will also rotate around the object you want to show.

When you touch left or right of your screen, you can rotate the "anchor" object so that you will get the effect you want.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use  `transform.RotateAround` and  `transform.LookAt(target);`
Using this should rotate the camera around the object.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html
        https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html